# Django project doesnt have wsgi.py and yet running

Tags: django, wsgi

I found a django project on github (don't know which version they used initially but I ran it using  1.4 and its working)..

Its directory was present in this way:

```
project/ 
        deploy/ manage.py, settings.py, urls.py
        project/ <apps>, urls.py
```

while there's no wsgi.py.. and in settings.py there isn't `WSGI_APPLICATION` variable.

my question is why this wsgi.py is used if we can work the projec with above settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `wsgi.py` is an optional file, for use when you deploy Django projects as a WSGI application.

But you can totally run any Django project just using manage.py's `runserver` command (though it's not great).